# Is there any significance to the comment on madeleines?

Tags: symbolism, serial-experiments-lain

Towards the end of the last episode of Serial Experiments Lain, we see Lain have a brief conversation with her father. At the end of it, her father says:

> Lain, I'll make us some nice tea next time. Hey, with some madeleines! Definitely. They're great!

This seems to be a reference to Marcel Proust's ["episode of the madeleine"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_Search_of_Lost_Time#Memory) in *In Search of Lost Time*. Assuming this is the case, is there any significance to this reference in relation to plot *beyond* the fact that (according to Wikipedia anyway - I haven't read Proust yet) in Proust, the madeleine is connected to a discussion of memory?

Given that this is followed (or follows, possibly) some comments on memory in the anime, it would make sense for this to be a "standalone" reference, but I'm wondering if there's any significance to this other than it *just* being a reference to a literary discussion of memory. (For instance, is there anything *specific* about Proust's discussion of memory that's also relevant in the context of SEL?)